# Creating a Rhombus with a framed message

Tags: c

Good evening,
I have been tasked with creating a dynamic Rhombus with a frame message inside.
I've been looking for a way to do this for a few hours now, but I'm honestly starting to lose my mind.

Note that my level is pretty basic, so my code doesn't include any complex materials.

I managed to create the upper half of the Rhombus, but I have no idea how to get the message exactly in the middle of it.

The user should be able to enter a string, a size and a character for the frame.
F.ex:

user input is:

5, $, Hello:

```
    $
   $ $
  $   $
 $     $
$ Hello $
 $     $
  $   $
   $ $
    $
```

My code so far (few unreferenced variables, ignore them):

```
        void framedMessage()
{
    int size = 6, i, sp, sym, a, b;
    char rSymbol = '$', str[100] = { "Hello" };
    //while ((strlen(str) % 2) == 0)
    //{
    //  puts("Please Enter a string (even number of letters will be denied):");
    //  gets(str);
    //}
    //puts("Please enter a char for the rhombus(NOTE that the letters 'C','M','S','P','E' will return as small chars and not capital:");
    //rSymbol = charInput();
    //size = numericalInput(strlen(str) + 2, 999);
    for (a = 0;a <= size;a++)
    {
        for (sp = 1;sp <= size;sp++)
        {
            if (sp == size && a == 0)
                printf("%c", rSymbol);
            if ((sp == size - a && a != 0))
            {
                printf("%c", rSymbol);
                for (;sp < size + a;sp++)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                    if (sp == size + a -2)
                        printf("%c", rSymbol);
                }
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        puts("");
    }

}
```

The top half of the Rhombus wasn't so hard, but now I have no idea how to put the message in a way that will fit the space perfectly (have in mind that the string can't have an even amount of characters because it would ruin the rhombus).

I would appreciate any help with this. constructive posts about the code itself (what should I try to improve, avoid using etc..) would be greatly received.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you should do this by hand, on grid paper. Then just translate your logical thought process into program code to do the same. Learning to do that is the whole purpose of your task, after all.

Comment: Turn off your screen. Take a piece of paper and write a *formula*, taking message length and line number, and returning the number of stars/spaces. Then turn the screen on and program it.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is exactly what my professor keeps telling me. I should start listening to his instructions more often. I guess my laziness got the better of me. I would definitely listen to your advice and write it down on paper. Thanks a lot. I needed this sort of encouragement to do this on my own.

Comment: You invited comments on the code. You could change `char str[100] = { "Hello" };` to the simpler and more efficient `char str[] = "Hello";` note the compiler will automatically size `str` to 6 elements and place a `nul` terminator at the end.

Comment: **hint** start with the line containing "hello" and the symbols either side. Create the triangle below it by gradually lengthening one string and shortening the other.  When this works add the opposite code before the "hello" output .  Always use **n** for input string length so it works with any input.

Answer (score 0):

Since in this example you have used 6 as the size. The total no of spaces in next line between the two '$'s will be 11. ie double the value of variable size -1. So you get the length of the string and use the below logic to get the string in the middle.

```
 len = strlen(str);
 x = ( (size*2-1) - len)/2
```

in the case x will be 3 
x No of spaces is required before and after str.